# Match 2 consecutive lines using grep or sed

Tags: sed, grep

I've just spent a couple of hours trying to detect resets on my system from the console log, where I have:

```
Boot up message  // 1st console output on a boot
Shutdown message // Last console output on a CLEAN shutdown
```

By using grep for the 2 lines above, on the console output, I have text that contains something like:

```
Boot up message
Shutdown message
Boot up message
Shutdown message
Boot up message
Boot up message
Shutdown message
```

Where the reset is detectable by 2 consecutive Boot messages.  I have a few thousand cycles to go through, so want to be able to use the '-n' switch with grep to print the cycle numbers, giving something like:

```
1:Boot up message
2-Shutdown message
3:Boot up message
4-Shutdown message
5:Boot up message
6:Boot up message  // reset occurred here
7-Shutdown message
```

How can I use sed/grep (in Cygwin) to find only the consecutive Boot messages?

Comment: awk would be better... `awk '{printf NR ":" $0} p == $0{printf "// reset occurred here"} {p=$0; printf "\n"}' log`

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Cygwin as it is installed on the client's system for other reasons, and I prefer bash/sed/grep than Windows solutions.  Unfortunately, awk is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -n 'N;/^\(Boot.*\)\n\1/=' file
```

(OR)

```
sed -n 'N;/^\(Boot.*\)\n\1/p' file
```

This will output a line number on which consecutive messages.

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
Boot up message
Shutdown message
Boot up message
Shutdown message
Boot up message
Boot up message
Shutdown message

$ sed -n 'N;/^\(Boot.*\)\n\1/p' file
Boot up message
Boot up message
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but it only picks up every other double-boot message.  Also, if I add the pre-reset-matched line numbers to find the position in the complete console output, it fails to find anything:

Comment: i.e.: `grep -n -e Boot -e Shutdown console.log | sed -n 'N;/^\(Boot.*\)\n\1/='` finds nothing (as expected) so I changed it to `grep -n -e Boot -e Shutdown console.log | sed -n 'N;/^\(.*Boot.*\)\n\1/='` to account for the first grep's line numbers.  Even if I can't have the console output's line numbers, the missing resets mean I still have to check large amounts of output for the intermediate resets.

Comment: @JasonEtherton, Try this: `sed -n 'N;/^.*\(Boot.*\)\n.*\1/='  file`

Comment: Hi.  Same result - still only every other reset.